# Bootstrap 3.3.x, how to get correct order of menu items for navbar when collapsed?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap newbie using 3.3.6, and having trouble creating a simple navbar based on the example Twitter provides in their documentation. The code I show below sets up a navbar that has two menu items on the top right corner. For large screens, it looks like:

`Brand                   Menu 1  Menu 2`

But when I collapse the navbar for the smallest screen, it shows:

`Brand
Menu 2
Menu 1`

How do I get the collapsed order to be:

`Brand
Menu 1
Menu 2`

?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top navbar-default-siteheader navbar-inner-siteheader">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header" >
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" 
                     role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Menu 2<span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>      

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" 
                    role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Menu 1<span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Item A</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Item B</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Item C</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </div>  <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div> <!-- /.container -->
</nav>
```

Comment: Why are you using navbar-right twice? Just combine your ULs into one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the 2 dropdown menus to be on the right, you don't have to create 2 `navbar-right`.

Just put the 2 `<li class="dropdown">` into a single `<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">`.

Like this :

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top navbar-default-siteheader navbar-inner-siteheader">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header" >
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" 
                    role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Menu 1<span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Item A</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Item B</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Item C</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" 
                     role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Menu 2<span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

            </ul>

        </div>  <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div> <!-- /.container -->
</nav>
```

Here's a JsFiddle : [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/g563e970/)